# iText - How to Clone a page of the document?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText 5 API to clone the page of a PDF. My requirement is as follows:
I have a document named "Test" which has 2 different pages. I need to clone the each pages i.e. if the test document is having two pages, i need to clone the first page & then the second page which in total makes 4 pages in the same Test document. I need this setup using iText API. I have tried out some code but it's giving me some exception & also doesn't satisfy my requirement.

**Code:**

```
public void clonePageOfPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException{
        Document doc = null;
        PdfReader reader = null;
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

        //Assign
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(sourcefile));
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destfile));

        doc = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, outputStream);
        doc.open();
        reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);

        for(int page = 0; page < reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++){
            PdfImportedPage importedPage = copy.getImportedPage(reader, page);

            //Duplicate
            for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                copy.addPage(importedPage);
            }
        }
        copy.freeReader(reader);

        reader.close();
        doc.close();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Please help me out with this.

**Updated Code**

```
public void clonePageOfPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException{
        //Document doc = null;
        PdfReader reader = null;
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

        //Assign
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(sourceFile));
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(destFile));

        //doc = new Document();

        reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
        reader.selectPages("1,1");
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
        stamper.close();

        reader.close();
        //doc.close();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

Can anyone help me with the updated code?

Comment: At first sight, you might think: *Hey, this Bruno-guy closed my question as a duplicate of a totally different question!* But give it a try. Throw away your `PdfCopy` code, and replace it with `PdfStamper` code. Use a very specific selection, such as `"1, 1, 2, 2"`. You will discover that the `selectPages()` method can also be used to repeat pages.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Hi thanks for the selectPages() method. However, I am unable to repeat the pages even if I repeat the selectPages() method. Can you demonstrate with a small snippet?

Comment: It should be as simple as this: `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src); reader.selectPages("1, 1, 2, 2"); PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));  stamper.close();`

Comment: @BrunoLowagie `reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
reader.selectPages("1,1,2,2");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
stamper.close();` 
This is the code I have used. But still i am not able to see the duplicate page in my output PDF. Any idea as to why?

Comment: No, that works for me. Which version of iText are you using? Can you share the PDF document?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am using iText version 5.
P.S. My source PDF is currently having only one page & I am trying to clone  the single page to make it 2 pages.

Comment: Version 5 could be anything from 5.0.0 to 5.5.12. Obviously, if you only have 1 page, you have to adapt the code like this: `PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream); reader.selectPages("1,1"); PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream); stamper.close();` (but that goes without saying; that's just common sense).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I am using version 5.5.12 of iText. I have used the same snippet that you have posted here. But still not able to clone the page in the document.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have my updated code there which I am currently using to clone the pages; however using the same code I am unable to clone the pages. If you don't mind, would just point out the mistake in the code?

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the problem. As for the first version of your own code, this is wrong: `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` because it adds the page only once. If you want to add it twice, you need `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)`.

Comment: You're right. My example used an old version of iText. I installed the most recent version, and it doesn't behave as I expect. There's only one page in the resulting PDF. That's odd, something must have changed, but I don't know from which version on. I'll undo my duplicate vote.

Comment: There is even a 5.5.13 since last week.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the `selectPages()` approach I suggested no longer works with recent versions of iText 5 (it worked with the older ones), so I looked at your original code, and I adapted it like this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    for(int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++) {
        PdfImportedPage importedPage = copy.getImportedPage(reader, page);
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            copy.addPage(importedPage);
        }
    }
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

These are the changes I made:

```
for(int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
```

Page numbers start at page 1, not at page 0, and that has an impact on your `for`-loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
```

If you want to add 2 pages instead of one, you need `i < 2` instead of `i < 1`.